# How to read text from a file using Python?

Tags: python

I have some header files in C that I want to read in Python. Is there a way to do this? For example, if I have a header file that contains the following code in C:

```
#define x 0x00
#define y 0x03
#define z 0x0003
```

Would I be able to extract this data using Python?

Comment: So, you just want to read the raw text from the .h files? If so, there is no difference in reading a .h from a .txt or whatever. Just reading text from a file. If you want to actually parse the code or do some kind of C interop from Python, the procedure is a bit different!

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do here. You mean you want to get back a mapping as in converting hex numbers? Is it `ntohs(0x0003)` as in *Capture all packets* in some socket protocol? Is it the Nvidia GeForce error codes or what?? More info needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
data = dict()
with open("file.h", "r") as f:
    for l in f:
        l = l.split(" ")
        data[l[1]] = l[2]
```

Comment: Many ways to achieve that. Easiest is probably using a full path in the first argument to `open()`, like `open('/path/to/file/here.h', 'r')`.

Comment: If you use the code from @Programmer the text from the file is read into a `dict` structure, so you'd have to traverse the dict to get to the text elements. It isn't supposed to "open" an application containing the text / document, if that's what you mean?

Comment: If that is what you want, then a dirty trick to open the system defined app for the given file-type could be: 

`import webbrowser` 

`webbrowser.open('/path/to/file.txt')`